# Using TYPE in PLSQL for multiple tables

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am using TYPE to get the rowtype in tables. I want to use it to retrieve the rowtypes of Customer and Supplier (i.e. multiple tables).

Below is the code for Customers, how do I retrieve Customer and Supplier with the same code?

```
TYPE dept_table_type is table of CUSTOMER%ROWTYPE
INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;
```

Thank you

Comment: You're trying to create a single PL/SQL table with all the columns from two real tables? Maybe you can explain what your end goal is. Is there a reason not to define a record type listing all the fields you actually need?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ROWTYPE of a cursor to do what you're trying to do:

```
CURSOR MULTI_TABLE_CURSOR IS
  SELECT *
    FROM CUSTOMER
    CROSS JOIN SUPPLIER;

TYPE DEPT_TABLE_TYPE IS TABLE OF MULTI_TABLE_CURSOR%ROWTYPE
  INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;
```

Note that you don't actually need to use the cursor if you don't have a use for it.

Best of luck.